# SQL Server Linked Server is getting an old view definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have a linked server that I am able to run views on. I have one view in particular that when I run it, the wrong data is returned. When I run sp_helptext on the view to get the definition, the definition is an old definition.

I asked someone who has the ability to access the linked server directly to take a look. When looking at the view on the actual server, it has the correct updated definition and the results come back correct.

Is there something I need to do for the linked server to get the correct definition?

Comment: Are you cetain that the linked server is connecting to the instance you think it is? If it's using a server name then ensure that the name resolves to the correct IP address. If it's using an instance name then ensure that the SQL Browser service on the target machine has been restarted since the instance configurations last changed (because it only enumerates instance information as the service starts up).

Comment: I'm guessing you're either using wrong database, server, schema or something else. You might wanna check object_id of your view AND make sure to specify the database.schema.viewname when you selecting. The last thing is mostly to debug so you're selecting from correct view